# Decouple or mock?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Suppose I have this class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // Top level function
    public function execute($command)
    {
        // Get output from system tool
        $output = $this->runTool($command);

        // Check output for errors
        if ($this->hasError($output))
            return false;

        // And parse success response from tool
        return $this->parseOutput($output);
    }

    // There we're make a call to system
    private function runTool($command)
    {
        return `/some/system/tool $command`;
    }
    [...]
}
```

I do not want to run system tool in my test, I want to replace a system call with predefined output.

So, the question is - should I create another class, move system call in it and mock that class in the test, or I can mock only that function of class which I will test?

Sure, both approaches will work, but which of them will be serve testing purposes better?

Comment: Additional: should I test each function in my test, or I can test only top level function that calls other?

Comment: you can mock the runTool method but you must to change the method visibility: phpunit can't mock private method. If you want i can show you a sample unit test for your class

Comment: Ofcource I want, it would be awesome help to getting started with testing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the single responsibility principle, you won't have this problem. Your class does not need to know how system calls are made, so you will have to use another class. You mock that.

IMO, in most cases when you need to mock protected or private methods, they do stuff that should be into another class and be mocked.

Comment: Sounds well, but I didn't say important thing: this class is abstract and provide top level *execute* function to child classes as an shortcut. So, should I test this class? I think, I shoud, because it contains sensible algorithms which convert plain output from tool (actually XML) into array. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, you should test the abstract class by creating an implementation just for testng purposes (not using any of the production child classes). Anyway it does not matter if the class is abstract. If the class needs to make a system call, it should use a mockable dependency, so you can check that the right system call is being invoked by the private methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it really depends on your infrastructure. Sometimes it is better to use Mock, sometimes Stub.

If the case is, that the class you want to test contains this unwanted method - use Mock and mock only this one function. That will make you sure, that any changes made to that class will be handled by the test.

If the unwanted function is a part of i.e. injected service or another class, which is not the domain of this particular test, you can create a stub.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test private method, you can use a workaround and invoke it via reflection as described in this [article](https://jtreminio.com/2013/03/unit-testing-tutorial-part-3-testing-protected-private-methods-coverage-reports-and-crap/) and discussed in this [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313492/testing-private-methods-not-working)

But i suggest you to change the method visibility to protected and mock only the behaviour of the runTool method.

As example, suppose the following modified version of your class (i don't know how other method work so i suppose that you want to test their behaviour and take this implementation as example):

```
<?php


namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service;


    class SomeClass
    {
        // Top level function
        public function execute($command)
        {
            // Get output from system tool
            $output = $this->runTool($command);

            // Check output for errors
            if ($this->hasError($output))
                return false;

            // And parse success response from tool
            return $this->parseOutput($output);
        }

        // There we're make a call to system
        protected function runTool($command)
        {
            return `/some/system/tool $command`;
        }

        private function hasError($output)
        {
            return $output == "error";
        }

        private function parseOutput($output)
        {
            return json_decode($output);
        }

    }
```

As suppose the following test case:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests;


class SomeClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testCommandReturnError()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Acme\DemoBundle\Service\SomeClass')
            ->setMethods(array('runTool'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock()
        ;

        $mock
        ->expects($this->exactly(1))
            ->method('runTool')
            ->with("commandName")
            ->will($this->returnValue("error"));

        $this->assertFalse($mock->execute("commandName"));
    }

    public function testCommandReturnCorrectValue()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Acme\DemoBundle\Service\SomeClass')
            ->setMethods(array('runTool'))
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock()
        ;

        $mock
            ->expects($this->exactly(1))
            ->method('runTool')
            ->with("commandName")
            ->will($this->returnValue('{"title":"myTitle"}'));

        $returnValue = $mock->execute("commandName");
        $this->assertEquals("myTitle", $returnValue->title);
    }

}
```

Hope this help